# Eclipse not showing drawables and layouts after deleting files

Tags: eclipse

I accidently deleted some files from my desktop that my project was depending on in eclipse(shift+del)
Now in eclipse my project is not showing

1. entire packages hierarchy
2. all the java class files
3. all the drawables in drawables folder also there is no drawable-hdpi etc mdpi etc folder
4. all the layouts in layouts folder
5. all the localized strings folder i.e. there is only one folder of values

I've tried to add all external library projects and jars my project was depending on but I am still unable to solve the problem

I've tried Project>>Restore from local history but amazingly the missing layouts, classes and drawables are not listed there

Answer (score 0):

just, create a new project and import the old project data.

Answer (score 0):

Change the theme with "classic" value. It works for me.